# filling the width of imageview without stretching the image

Tags: ios, swift

i have an imageview in which it's image fill the width and height without stretching the image .. the width is always the same .. but the height change depending on the image's height ...

I tried `scaleToFill` and got this stretched image:

[image]

tried also `scaleToAspectFit` and got this which will not fill the width:

[image]

How to fill the width and change height of the image view so it will not be stretched?

when i tried `scaleToAspectFill` with clear background i will get this:

[image]

what i want is to fill width and change height of the imageview so it wont be stretched .. something like this:

[image]

Comment: Do you want the black background to cover the full imageView? Or is it ok if the image is not fully viisble but covers the whole imageView?

Comment: @RakeshaShastri no i want the whole image to be visible

Comment: Then you'll have to reduce your imageView size and add backgroundViews or put the imageView on a backgroundView of the required color.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri sorry this is totally new to me .. what is backgroundview?

Comment: @RakeshaShastri can you tell me with an example please

Comment: @lama - please add an image showing what end result you're looking for. It's not clear what you actually want.

Comment: @AshleyMills just updated my post

Comment: you can using auto layout set aspect ration so the image has that correct and then you only need to set width in this case for the image view and the image will grow and keep the ration

Comment: you have to exaplain how you are setting the `imageView`'s frame - directly, or using autolayout? if autolayout, include all your constraints

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `scaleToAspectFill`.

More details:

> The option to scale the content to fill the size of the view. Some portion of the content may be clipped to fill the view’s bounds.

from https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/contentmode

**After OP's comment:** You maybe want to set `backgroundColor` of `UIImageView` to `clear`. Then your image (with `scaleToAspectFit`) will be visible without additional frame.

Comment: The OP does not want this I am afraid.

Comment: Yeah, he added comment after my response. I added second option to solve this.

Comment: tried the second option and the same .. some of the image will be cutted

Comment: No, second approch doesn't allow image to be cut (if you don't do something weird / unconventional in your code). It requires image to be scaled in way that it will be inside frame. Maybe I don't understand what you want to achieve...

Comment: Ok, my last proposal suggests `scaleToAspectFit`, not `scaleToAspectFill`. But I'm afraid that I still don't understand, what you want to achieve.

Comment: @franiis Both your answers were correct - but he keeps changing the question.

Comment: @AshleyMills I think so. I also think that my answer still can hel someone, who will find this question - so I'm willing to leave it. I maybe able to update my answer, but not right now.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so based on the update to your question, you need to use

```
imageView.contentMode = scaleToAspectFill
```

and adjust the height of your imageView

You can do this by getting the size of your image, and calculating the height-to-width ratio. Then you can adjust your imageView's constraints…

```
if let imageSize = imageView.image?.size {
    let ratio = imageSize.height / imageSize.width

    imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.widthAnchor, multiplier: ratio).isActive = true
}
```

Comment: this is working fine .. but it will mess the design .. i mean the button under will not be shifted no it will remain in the same place and it will be on the imageview ..

Comment: You've got to be joking. You asked a question, and @franiis gave you a correct answer. You updated your question, so they gave you _another_ correct answer. You updated your question _again_ - and I answered it. Now you're adding a button. How is anyone supposed to answer your question if you don't give them all the information?

Comment: if you please can check last image i uploaded .. you can see some buttons and labels in which they became on the imageview

Comment: no no ... i didn't add the button .. the button is there from the start but it was under the imageview

Comment: How would anyone know about a button that is _underneath_ an imageView? This is a prime example of how to get people to ignore your questions in future - if you keep changing the goalposts, what's the point in answering?

Comment: am sorry .. but my question was about the image so i thought there is no need to talk about the other things...

Comment: I have rolled back your last question edit. Changing your question after you've received answers is inappropriate, as it invalidates the answers you've received. It can even make those answers wrong, and adversely affect the reputation of those who answered. If you now have a new or additional question, create a new post and ask it there; you can link back to this one if needed for reference.

Answer (score -1):

Use scaleToFill contentMode with clipToBounds = true
It will solve your problem.

Comment: Sorry my mistake. i mean scaleToAspectFit with clipToBounds. When you do scaleToAspectFit, it fits the image in imageView and then clipToBounds will make the image fit the ImageView.